# Drop into ListView item

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, c++-cx, c++-winrt

In a UWP app I need to implement drag from a `ListView` to a `ListViewItem` in another `ListView`.

I've tried to simply `AllowDrop` and all the other stuff to support drag&drop functionality, but this way the target `ListViewItem` stays highlighted in gray.

I wonder if I need to do something particular or if this scenario is even supported.

Comment: c++ tag has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Why not? I write uwp apps in C++

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I thought it's c#

Comment: Actually to be specific it’s C++/CX and C++/WinRT, but well I preferred to use a more generic tag

Comment: Well, that'll be consider as a spam tags. That's why you have to be specific in your tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement `Drag and Drop` operation, the following is an overview of what you need to do to enable drag and drop in your app:

> 1. Enable dragging on an element by setting its **CanDrag** property to true.
> 2. Build the data package. The system handles images and text automatically, but for other content, you'll need to handle the **DragStarted** and **DragCompleted** events and use them to construct your own data package.
> 3. Enable dropping by setting the **AllowDrop** property to **true** on all the elements that can receive dropped content.
> 4. Handle the **DragOver** event to let the system know what type of drag operations the element can receive.
> 5. Process the **Drop** event to receive the dropped content.

You could see the detailed information on [Drag and drop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/drag-and-drop) document.

The official [Drag & Drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop/cpp) was for your reference.

Comment: I don’t simply want to drag & drop, I want to drag an item inside another (example: moving a file into a folder). Following those steps it ends up with the destination item highlighted in gray, with no way to get back at its normal state

Comment: Here you go, just drop a file from the system File Explorer to a ListView item in the app, it will stay highlighted: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApU6tnjXLHfheUUOty5N9Q8-E9Y

Comment: @FelaAmeghino I tested your code. Did you want to move file from outside of the app to your app inside and make the original file is not available in it's original palce?

Comment: I want to be able to drop to a specific ListViewItem without having it to stay gray after the drop

Comment: @FelaAmeghino Did you mean that you do not want the ListViewItem to be selected after the `Drop` operation is completed?

Comment: It’s not selected, it is glitched

Comment: @FelaAmeghino I'm sorry. I still could not understand what you say about "glitched". Maybe, you could post some screenshots.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here you go: https://giphy.com/gifs/xBcEtaeio4I1Q5dAYQ
Seems that the item keeps `PointerOver` visual state, no way to reset it programmatically (even setting it to `Normal` works only till you over it again)